# Return data from Camunda process when started through rest-engine

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, camunda

I have a Camunda process called partnerPortal. This accepts 3 variables as,

```
{
  "variables": {
    "userId" : {
      "value" : "user1"
  },
    "userName" : {
      "value" : "childProtect"
  },
    "accountType" : {
      "value" : "ideamart"
    }
  }
}
```

I call this process using Camunda rest-engine with the endpoint ***"engine-rest/process-definition/key/{processId}/start"*** using a separate spring-boot application. My requirement is, I want to return data from the Camunda-engine to the external spring-boot application when the process completes (Just like a regular API call).

For example, if I start the process using **"engine-rest/process-definition/key/partnerPortal/start"**, I want to receive a JSON array from the Camunda engine to the spring-boot application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/reference/rest/process-definition/post-start-process-instance/

Request Body:

- withVariablesInReturn
  Indicates if the variables, which was used by the process instance during execution, should be returned. Default value: false

Request

POST /process-definition/aProcessDefinitionId/start

POST /process-definition/key/aProcessDefinitionKey/start

Request body:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "someDate": {
      "value": "2021-09-08T00:00:00.0+0000",
      "type": "date"
    }
  },
   "withVariablesInReturn": true
}
```

Response

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "method": "GET",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-instance/d1d09e6b-99d0-11ec-b2a5-00ff01996606",
            "rel": "self"
        }
    ],
    "id": "d1d09e6b-99d0-11ec-b2a5-00ff01996606",
    "definitionId": "tcb-process:2:902391b6-99d0-11ec-b2a5-00ff01996606",
    "businessKey": null,
    "caseInstanceId": null,
    "ended": true,
    "suspended": false,
    "tenantId": null,
    "variables": {
        "result": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "abc",
            "valueInfo": {}
        },
        "someDate": {
            "type": "Date",
            "value": "2021-09-08T08:00:00.000+0800",
            "valueInfo": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, cannot believe I overlooked this. But I was just wondering using this method to get values as the output from the process is a good practice.

Comment: That's what it is for